# How do you input a line into a array separated as array elements?(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Using a scanner to read a line of input. I thought there was a way to directly insert the line into an array and have it separate into string elements (divided by spaces).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        String[][] partners = new String[2][numberOfStudents];
        partners[1] = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code you tried to the question

Comment: You mean myString.split(" ") ?

Comment: What do you want your code to do?  It seems to be a little unclear.

Comment: well bacicly i want to get an input of names and sort it. So i was looking for a quick way to input the names into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to rewrite your code to possibly be what you want.  Could you try to specify exactly what you're trying to do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
       //input.nextLine();
       String[][] partners = new String[2][numberOfStudents];
       for(int i=0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
       {
          partners[1][i] = input.nextLine();
       }
    }
}
```

I think you're looking for split.
For example:

```
    String val="I am a String";
    String [] tabDelimitedVals=val.split(" ");
```

This is seen in the stack overflow post here:
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

To read from a file, you can use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

The above was taken from: [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Together, you can do:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    String val=br.readLine();
    String [] splitted=val.split(" ");
}
finally {
   br.close();
}
```

Comment: i realized that was possible but i was looking for a way without the for loop for efficiency.

Comment: Doing it without the for loop is not reasonable.

Comment: so there's no direct way to input the line? without the for loop?

Comment: Please read the code, where it says: "nextLine".  It's grabbing the entire line when you do it.  Anyway, it doesn't seem like you need a two-dimensional array for this problem.